# Why cannot I import a .py file to another within the same directory?

Tags: python, import, directory, pycharm

I have the following 4 python files within the folder `SubFolder`, assembled as such:

```
   CodeFolder
       SubFolder
           GeneticAlgorithm.py
           main.py
           heuristic1.py
           heuristic2.py
```

I am trying to import the file `GeneticAlgorithm.py` within my `main.py` file, using the import statement at the beginning of the class:

```
import GeneticAlgorithm
```

The problem: PyCharm is highlighting this and says "*no module named GA*".

Any clues as to what may be causing this issue and how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: When you run the code, do you get an error, or is the issue just with the PyCharm highlighting? Sometimes IDEs can mistakenly get mad at an import.

Comment: You could try adding `__init__.py` in SubFolder directory

Comment: Josh, It is a sort of a mix as I have errors in the code so this is not the only issue. But it gets highlighted in the beginning and I am thinking it may be causing the entire thing to flop! Olahsymbo, I will try doing that!

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you might not have GA module in your GeneticAlgorithm.py

If you do, then you can do similar to below:

Similar to your folder structure:

[image]

From `main.py` call GeneticAlgorithm.py. For example:

```
from GeneticAlgorithm import GA


def main():
    ga_obj = GA(mutation_rate=0.5)
    print("Call GA module")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If we look at the GeneticAlgorithm.py

```
class GA:
    def __init__(self, mutation_rate):
        self.mutation = mutation_rate
```

We have GA class.

This is a simple demonstration of how you can use.